# Ubuntu 20.04 first boot freeze on login right after install with nomodeset (i5 9400 and 3080 ti)

Tags: system-installation, login, freeze, gpu

I installed ubuntu on my PC but it's now freezing right on the login page. I was unable to install it at all due to a black screen but then I set the cvar nomodeset and it managed to install. However, after installing it just boots up to a frozen log in screen. What could be the issue? I'm guessing it has something to do with my GPU (3080 ti) from what I've read online.

Comment: Can you boot to the desktop with `nomodeset`, and disable Wayland (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and see if that resolves your issue? Nvidia drivers are known not to work well with Wayland?

Comment: I have nomodeset on and it freezes when it gets to login. I'm downloading 21.04 right now to give that version a shot.